# Firebase Retrieving Data, returning FATAL ERROR Index Out of Range

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Retrieving Data, returning FATAL ERROR Index Out of Range

I have this class that retrieves items from Firebase:

[image: Class reference Picture]

Now when I try to get that data an place into something for example I would do,

```
let item = [CalendarItem]()
let items = item[item.count] <-- ERROR HERE

textLabel.text = items.name
```

However I get this error (fatal error: Index out of range}

Here are the items in the console that were created at an earlier stage:

[image: Firebase console items]

I did a `print(item.count)` and I got 0 hence the error, but I don't understand why if the items are in the console.

Somebody point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Good to see that you found the cause of the problem. For future questions: please post the actual code and JSON as text, instead of posting pictures of them. StackOverflow does a good job of highlighting them and having them as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual code/data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out... just wasn't actually calling an observe to load the items into the array

```
    ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                print(snapshot.value!)
                var newItems: [CalendarItem] = []
                for item in snapshot.children {
                     let calendarItem = CalendarItem(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                     newItems.append(calendarItem)
                }
               self.calanderDate = newItems
               //self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
```